# Why am I able to access my service through ‘port’ and not ‘nodePort’?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, port

I am new to Kubernetes and stuck at this point. Please share references to the answers as well. Following is my simple `.yml` file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-depl
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-serv-load
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer  
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30001
```

And the following is the output of the services.

```
$ kubectl get services 
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
test-serv-load      LoadBalancer   10.0.68.36   <my_pub_IP>     8080:30001/TCP   97m
kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.0.0.1     <none>          443/TCP          3h30m
```

According to my understanding, Nginx should be accessible through `<my_pub_IP>:30001` but strangely it is accessible through `<my_pub_IP>:8080` and not `<my_pub_IP>:30001`.

I have researched over the internet for days and am not able to find any reason. Please let me know if I am missing something in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The service type is `LoadBalancer`, so it should be accessible on the `<Public-IP>:targetport`, as expected. The `nodePort` field is only valid when the service type is `NodePort`, here the field has no meaning, you can remove it from the manifest.

Perhaps, in order to understand this further, you can change the service type to `NodePort` and then try and access it through `<Node-IP>:30001`. (In this case, the `port` field will become optional, since the traffic received on the `nodePort` will be routed to the service)

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) is further reading into Kubernetes services and how different service types work.